# No warning with array_count_values if null

Tags: php, cakephp

In a cakephp model i writed direct counter like this

```
        // array_layers_count
        $array_layers = array($val['Zombiesindexstats']['layer1'], etc... );
        $array_layers_count = array_count_values($array_layers);
        if ($array_layers_count['yes']) {
            $results[$key]['Zombiesindexstats']['layers_count'] = $array_layers_count['yes'];
        } else {
            $results[$key]['Zombiesindexstats']['layers_count'] = 0;
        }
```

If there is no 'yes' index, i have always the warning 'Undefined index: yes in..' in logs. How to make it quiet ?

Comment: `isset` read about it

Comment: use if(!empty($array_layers_count['yes'])  )

Comment: @miglio: `empty()` is nasty function and shouldn't be used. `empty(0)` is TRUE. isset() is far more reliable in this kind of situation, especially when you don't know what OP's storing at that array key.